# Как в объект передать зависимость, минуя методы и свойства этого объекта?

Tags: c#

Есть следующие типы в пространстве имен:

```
namespace Model {
   public interface IData {
      void Send(string str);
   }
   public class Test {
      public void Run() {
        // (1)
      }
   }
}
```

В методе Test.Run для его работы должна оказаться ссылка на объект с реализацией IData.

Есть следующая реализация интерфейса IData и код для работы с Test.

```
class Data : Model.IData {
    public void Send(string str) { }     
}     

var d = new Data();
var t = new Test();

// (2)
```

Какой код должен быть вместо `(1)` и `(2)`, чтобы в Test.Run оказалась ссылка на Data?

При этом в определении класса Test нельзя что-либо менять, нельзя добавлять конструктор(ы), методы, свойства и поля, и нельзя менять сигнатуру метода Run.

Также нельзя использовать Singleton.

p.s.
Это не для "размять мозги", как сказали в комментах. Есть огромное количество кода. И есть просто драконовский анализатор кода. Добавлять/менять правила в анализаторе не будут. Код Model менять нельзя и синглтоны исключены, а в Test.Run надо добавить зависимость. На вопрос, - как? Ответили, - как хотите так и делайте. 
Если есть идеи - напишите как, а не минусуйте вопрос.

Comment: Глобальная `static` переменная.

Comment: `static` тоже не подходит.

Comment: Унаследовать `Test` от класса, где будут нужные свойства/поля.

Comment: наследовать тоже нельзя.

Comment: Это реальная задача или так, мозги размять?

Comment: есть анализатор кода. добавлять/менять правила в нем не будут. код Model менять нельзя и синглтоны исключены. а в Test.Run надо добавить зависимость. на вопрос, - как? сказали, - как хотите так и делайте.

Comment: Если код можно вставлять только в отмеченные места а глобальные переменные и синглтоны запрещены, то задача, похоже, неразрешима.

Comment: _"задача, похоже, неразрешима."_ -- есть решение. с помощью Cecil, можно модифицировать сборки. но не хотелось бы его использовать.

Comment: В new нужно использовать только Data и Test, или можно производные классы? И можно ли менять сигнатуры конструкторов производных классов?

Comment: _"можно производные классы?"_ -- а что даст наследование Test? метод Run не виртуальный.

Comment: Если синглтон нельзя, какой-нибудь контекст? Thread local storage?

Comment: Да и пофиг что невиртуальный. Создаём производный класс Test2, даём ему ссылку на Data, в Run проверяем какого мы типа и если мы есть Test2, приводимся к нему и выцарапываем ссылку.

Comment: Синглтон нельзя, а статические объекты/поля можно? `static Dictionary<Test, IData>`?

Comment: _"статические объекты/поля можно?"_ -- нет. а _"Thread local storage"_ - никогда не использовал. вы использовали его? он быстро работает?

Comment: TLS - это кусок памяти, выделенный потоку. Работает не медленнее обычной памяти.

Comment: реализация TLS в .NET - это `Thread.SetData` и `Thread.GetData`?

Comment: @Stack: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Я думаю, что больше подойдёт пара Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot/Thread.GetNamedDataSlot.

Comment: @VladD `ThreadLocal` кажется не подходит, т.к. его надо как-то передать в Test.Run, а это проблема.

Comment: @Stack: Угу, переделал на GetData/SetData.

Comment: @kff: Точно, вы правы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33084/discussion-on-question-by-stack-------).

Answer (score 4):

Вот рабочий пример с thread local storage:

```
namespace Model
{
    public interface IData
    {
        void Send(string str);
    }
    public class Test
    {
        public void Run()
        {
            LocalDataStoreSlot slot = Thread.GetNamedDataSlot("dict");
            var dict = (Dictionary<Model.Test, Model.IData>)Thread.GetData(slot);
            var d = dict[this];
        }
    }
}

namespace ThreadLocalTest
{
    class Data : Model.IData
    {
        public void Send(string str) { }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var d = new Data();
            var t = new Model.Test();

            LocalDataStoreSlot slot = Thread.AllocateNamedDataSlot("dict");
            var dict = new Dictionary<Model.Test, Model.IData>();
            Thread.SetData(slot, dict);
            dict[t] = d;
            t.Run();
            Thread.FreeNamedDataSlot("dict");
        }
    }
}
```

По поводу других возможных опций, вот ещё: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html (это пригодится, если вы хотите протащить контекст через границу `await`).

Answer (score 1):

В порядке дурацкого предложения.

Создаём новый класс, который слушает сетевой порт. В конструктор передаём адрес объекта типа `Data`. В `Test.Run` подключаемся к порту и получаем адрес.

Можно также использовать вместо сетевых соединений pipe или класть адрес в файл с фиксированным расположением.

Comment: насколько такой способ будет быстро работать? а адрес во время передачи должен быть фиксирован, но это проблематично из-за GC.
вариант нашел - WCF In-process communication. может его использовать?

Comment: Не особо быстрый способ. Но если обращений к сокету будет немного, то вряд ли будет заметна потеря быстродействия. Чтобы избежать смены адреса GC можно использовать оператор fixed. Наверное, можно как-то и через WCF IPC, но тут я пас.