# Как именовать методы/функции?

Tags: c#, .net, code-style

```
using DAO.Operations;
namespace BBL.Operations
{

    public class OperationService
    {            
        public Operation Get(int id) {}
        public IEnumerable<Operation> GetAll() {}
        public void Add(Operation operation) {}

        //или

        public Operation GetOperation(int id) {}
        public IEnumerable<Operation> GetOperations() {}            
        public void AddOperation(Operation operation) {}
    }    
}
```

Как принято называть методы/функции? Какие рекомендации существуют на сей счет?

**UPD:**
В приведенном мной примере я указал противоречивые конструкции: короткая форма `Get()` против более полной `GetOperations()` мне хочется понять в каких случаях правильней использовать тот или иной способ, какие плюсы/минусы меня могут возникнуть позднее.

Comment: Рекомендации - [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov покажите конкретное место из этого гайдлайна, отвечающее на вопрос автора.

Comment: есть naming conventions. см. [Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Stack я попросил показать конкретное место.

Comment: @andreycha _"я попросил показать конкретное место"_ -- мой комментарий появился намного позже вашего ответа. но в вашем ответе есть только ваше мнение, но нет ссылки на ваше конкретное место. пожалуйста добавьте его в свой ответ. иначе почему вы хотите чтобы я показал мое конкретное место? и если вы обратите внимание, то заметите, что мой комментарий был адресован не вам, а автору вопроса.

Comment: @andreycha как я понял из вашего [комментария](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476863/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c/476893#comment542849_476893), вы против конкретики. или я ошибаюсь, и все зависит от ситуации?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы выбрал первый вариант. Потому что второй вариант предполагает некоторое дублирование и лишнюю писанину:

```
var operationService = new OperationService();
var all = operationService.GetOperations();
```

в сравнении с

```
var operationService = new OperationService();
var all = operationService.GetAll();
```

Если вы правильно называете переменные, то кратких вариантов достаточно.

Comment: @Bald56rus нет. У вас в классе `Operation` есть методы получения и сохранения операций, которые возвращают и принимают тип `Operation`. Я бы оставил в `Operation` только данные и какое-то очень базовое поведение, а все эти методы выделил в какой-нибудь OperationRepository/OperationManager/OperationLoader.

Comment: @Bald56rus обновил ответ.

Comment: @Bald56rus понял.

Answer (score 4):

Существует [Framework Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - набор правил для создания библиотек, которые будут расширять .NET Framework и взаимодействовать с ним.

В частности там написано, что для методов [надо использовать PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)

```
public class Object {
public virtual string ToString();
}
```

Что касается `Get` или `GetOperation` - никакие соглашения о стиле кодирования такого не регламентируют, и выбор зависит исключительно от предпочтений автора кода. В том числе может быть

```
    public Operation Get(int id) {}
    public IEnumerable<Operation> Get() {}
```

т.к. язык позволяет перегрузку функций.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, но в указанном мной примере я так так использую *PascalCase*, вопрос был скорее в `Get()` или `GetOperation()`

Answer (score 1):

Очевидные методы лучше называть проще.

Т.е. методы get\set\add\clear - проще так и именовать.
Другое дело, если ваш add внутри выбирает по какой то сложно логике что ему делать.

Тогда лучше явно писать:

`AddOperationWhen(?)`

`GetWithoutRights()` или `GetAsAdmin()` или даже иногда лучше `GetOperationsAsAdmin()`

Comment: Используйте `` для оформления `кода` и названий `классов`/`методов`/`переменных`.

Answer (score 0):

Второй лучше. Объясню на примере:

```
Operation NextMove = new Operation();

/*
...
Много... много строк кода
*/

NextMove.Get(n);

//or

NextMove.GetOperation(n);
```

Конечно среда вам "подставит плечико", но..., лучше ходить ногами, а не на костылях. Исключение, будет тот случай интерфейса, так интерфейс предполагает, наследование его множеством классов. Вообще, если вы что либо можете указать явно - укажите.

P.S. Название GetOperations(), я бы заменил на GetOperationsAll()

Comment: а вариант `NextMove` дать более осмысленное название и не вводить в заблуждение ни себя ни других? как пишут в книге Мартина "Чистый код"

Comment: @Bald56rus -- фокус в том что, называя операцию Get(), вы скорее всего и переменные поименуете так чтоб лишний раз пальцем не двинуть, и потом будете чесать в затылке.

Comment: ну я скорее стараюсь давать осмысленные выражения т.е. я бы скорее экземпляр класса назвал например `var operationManager = new Operation();` спасибо за мнение, если же не заморачиваться и давать непонятные имена то да второй вариант выглядит более предпочтительным

Comment: *"Много... много строк кода"* -- а вот такого не должно быть :).